# Entity Framework изменение таблиц

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Всем добрый день! С помощью EF добавил таблицы Users и Audios, сам EF автоматически сгенерил третью таблицу для связи:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public List<Audio> Audios { get; set; }
}
public class Audio
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Artist { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

При попытке добавить юзера со списком аудиозаписей все нормально, однако когда пытаюсь добавить другого юзера с аудиозаписями, которые есть у первого, выкидывает ошибку, мол нельзя одинаковые аудио добавлять.
Если я удалю у второго пользователя аудио, которые уже есть в бд, не установится связь. Думал отдельно залить пользователя и недостающие аудио, а потом напрямую с помощью sql запроса добавить в таблицу связи, но этот способ кажется костыльным и неправильным. Надеюсь на вашу помощь!

Comment: Надо посмотреть сам код добавления. Используется ли .Include(a=>a.Users) и .Include(u=>u.Audios)? Там у EF много аспектов, но самый простой вариант реализации почему-то как раз работает, нежели сложный.

Comment: Этот вопрос задавался тут 100500 раз. Поищите по ключевым словам "Entity Framework", "добавление".

Comment: @PavelMayorov лично я не нашел, думаю из 100500 вы хотя бы 5 ссылок предложите?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решилось:

```
db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
//цикл ниже гарантирует существование дочерних элементов(аудио) в таблице
foreach (var userAudio in user.Audios)
{
    db.Audios.AddOrUpdate(userAudio);
}
db.Users.AddOrUpdate(user);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Аккуратнее с `AddOrUpdate` - это довольно глючный метод. В частности, он никогда не сообщит вам, Add или Update он на самом деле сделал.

Comment: И уж точно не имеет никакого смысла делать `db.Users.AddOrUpdate(user);` после строчки `db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;`!

Comment: @PavelMayorov то есть мне оставить только Add?

Comment: @Buka db.Entry(user).State=EntityState.Modified делает то же самое что и db.Users.AddOrUpdate(user). Они являются взаимоисключающими, поэтому в данном случае ты проделал лишнее действие

Comment: @ValeriyPosvistak практика же выше показала, что этот параметр говорит о том что зависимая сущность так же изменена, и именно благодаря ему я избавился от ошибки